# Dragging image element from outside react to pixijs canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I currently have a sidebar created into Pixi.js, I can drag/drop element from this sidebar to the canvas (same canvas element).

Because I want to style a lot more the sidebar, I would like to know if there is a possibility to drag an image element from a sidebar outside of pixijs canvas (react handled) to the canvas.

I was thinking about using the `onDragStart` event from the `<img />` and automatically add the sprite to the canvas, but not really sure how to do the handling on the pixijs side of things.

Basically want to do something like this https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Drop_DOM_Element.html

Any ideas?

Regards